# Unable to pass values between Activities in Android

Tags: java, android

I am using 2.3.3 version of the Android SDK and I'm trying to pass data between two activities using the following code

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainAct.this, FriendsActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra(USER_NAME, ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.username)).getText());
MainAct.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

In the `FriendsActivity` i'm retrieving the value using

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String user = b.getString(MainAct.USER_NAME);
```

But the `user` is null after these lines are executed. Not sure whats wrong here. Read similar questions on SO http://goo.gl/zOJfa but still the problem continue to be seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username)).getText().toString() instead. getText() on an EditText View doesn't return a string, it returns an Editable Object.

Comment: I just figured out the same. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: No problem, had a similar issue myself several months ago.

Comment: Of course, I'm going to... I tried then itself.. but couldn't as there is 5 min time limit.

Answer (score 1):

just do (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username)).getText().toString() you are able to get string value.